# how to show showBusyIndicator into xdk html5 hybrid application?

Tags: intel-xdk

i added the cordova-notification plugin into intel-xdk appication, when try to show the indicator i get this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'showBusyIndicator' of undefined

this is the code:

```
$(document).on("change","#sel_produttori", function(evt) 
{ 
    intel.xdk.notification.showBusyIndicator();
});
```

maybe it is strange the plugin is listed in the first window but not in the second one.

[image: plugin manager]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many of the 'intel.xdk' plugins have been or are being deprecated in favor of their standard core Cordova counterparts.  I would recommend using that instead.

The problem you're running into appears to be that you've included the standard Cordova notification plugin, but you're trying to access the intel.xdk notification plugin, which is not included and therefore doesn't exist in your app.

It looks like the corresponding method on the standard Cordova Notification plugin was deprecated some time back and isn't there anymore.  You might want to try a plugin like this:

https://github.com/filfat-Studios-AB/cordova-plugin-spinnerdialog

It seems to work for me but, as always, use at your own risk.

Comment: i get "unimplemented api emulation" dialog on the emulator, is it normal?

Comment: Yes, that's normal.  The emulator has a fixed set of Cordova plugins that it emulates, any others will either trigger that dialog, or if it can't tell that it's a plugin will just show up as an undefined variable.  If you have a USB connected Android device, you can test and debug even with 3rd party apps.